# SimCity 4 for Intel-based Macs?

Tags: macos, simcity-4

I used to love playing SimCity 3000 and was wondering recently what new versions have come out since then. I found SimCity 4 which sounds pretty cool.

I switched to an Intel based MacBook Pro half a year ago, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimCity_4#Intel_Macintoshes) lists couple of bugs that are told to render SimCity unusable.

Does anyone have some experience with it? Is it really that bad? Do you think it isn't worthwhile to buy it for a Mac? What if I installed Windows on my Mac and ran SimCity like that? Would it change anything?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Windows emulation/installation on Macs is near perfect. Getting Windows on your Mac and then playing the Sim City's in that would be the best choice.

And for SC4, no matter how good your computer is, it's still going to lag. It was just poorly programmed for certain scaling tasks.

Comment: Hi Sho, do you suppose that the Wikipedia article (in my OP) refers to the Mac port? The article doesn't clarify that, I'm not sure, maybe it speaks of running it on Windows on a Mac (as you suggest)? Have you tried it? -- Re "It's still going to lag": Can you expand on that?

Comment: No it is definitely referring to the Mac port. Aspyr would not attempt to release a patch for the windows version. Running windows on a intel Mac is the same as running Windows on a PC from the point of view of simcity with the same hardware and so would not affect the game.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "for Mac" version; a port of the Windows ver:
[here!](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000BB2P5Q)

In my experience, it's less stable than the Win version but is workable.  It does get stroppy with a large number of add-ins I found.  It works fine on my 3y/o Macbook...

Comment: Does your Macbook have a PowerPC proc, or an Intel? I've also found http://www.application-systems.de/simcity/, but a small icon on the left says "PPC only"...

Comment: Intel.  2.2GHz Core 2 Duo to be precise....

Comment: Sounds promising. So, of all the bugs described on the Wikipedia article I referred to, don't you experience any of these?

Comment: I've not experienced the 95k+ crash to my knowledge but graphics corruption is relatively common.  To be honest I just put that down to it being run on an onboard graphics card.  I don't use the driving mode so I can't vouch for that but to be honest the graphics issue doesn't render it unplayable (although obviously YMMV) and really if I had wanted a gaming machine, I'd have bought a PC...